# How to include an automatic download in my custome python package?

Tags: python-3.x, package, spacy, packaging, pypi

I've created a python package and built it with the help of [python packaging instructions](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). Now I'm trying to add all the dependencies and extra packages that need to be downloaded and used in this package, such as tqdm, termcolor, and spacy. As I saw in a sample project [here](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/main/setup.py), I have to include these packages in the `install_requires` in the `setup.py` file, Although, because I use one of SpaCy pipelines in my package, I need to run the following command too:

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

I tried adding this command to entry_point in the setup.py, though I couldn't rebuild the package after

```
entry_points={  
        'console_scripts': [
            '!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg',
        ],
    }
```

Here is the [Github code](https://github.com/mitramir55/PassivePy). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can provide the model package as one of the requirements like this, but note that this points to one particular version of the model:

```
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0/en_core_web_sm-3.0.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm
```

See: https://spacy.io/usage/models#production

Comment: do you have any suggestions as to how the pipeline can automatically be downloaded along with the package? I've been able to add a requirements file, but when I try to add this link to the `dependency_links` in the `setup.py` file, it does not recognize or install the package.

Comment: Dependency links have been deprecated for a very long time. Use `package_name @ url` in `install_requires`.